# How to split JSON Object in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, api

I'm using a JSON API with Angular 4 frontend, now I'm trying to show the data of this [JSON Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es0sS.png).

I used the following code:

```
<div *ngFor="let Questionnaire of struc.data">
    <span>{{Questionnaire.attributes.content.headline}}</span><br>
    <span>{{Questionnaire.attributes.content.text}}</span><br>
    <span>{{Questionnaire.attributes.content.question}}</span>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let Questionnaire of struc.data">
  <li>{{Questionnaire.attributes.content.answers}}</li>
</div>
```

It works, but I get my answer in the format:

- überhaupt nicht,Sehr selten,einige Male,häufig,sehr häufig

instead of looking like this:

- überhaupt nicht
- Sehr selten
- einige Male
- häufig
- sehr häufig

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this **`Questionnaire.attributes.content.answer.split(',')`**,

```
<div *ngFor="let Questionnaire of struc.data">
 <div *ngFor="let ans of Questionnaire.attributes.content.answers.split(',')">
     <li>{{ans}}</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

**`EDIT`**

After your JSON object post, seems answers is an array, you need to do this,

```
<div *ngFor="let Questionnaire of struc.data">
     <div *ngFor="let ans of Questionnaire.attributes.content.answers">
         <li>{{ans}}</li>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/9iPlJ2YTbMVHANLYEgot?p=preview)**

Comment: I did but I got this error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined  .. I think its because I'm working with an array not a String due to my JSON Object, I just don't know how to changes this